# lcov.info not getting scanned by sonarqube

Tags: typescript, karma-jasmine, sonarqube-scan, karma-coverage, lcov

I am trying to scan the coverage of my code using `coverageIstanbulReporter` on the sonarqube. Here is my karma.conf.js file:

```
module.exports = function (config) {
config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular/cli'],
    plugins: [
        require('karma-jasmine'),
        require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
        require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
        require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
        require('@angular/cli/plugins/karma')
    ],
    client: {
        clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
    },
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
        reports: ['html', {
            'lcovonly': {
                "directory": "coverage",
                "filename": "lcov.info",
                "subdirectory": "lcov"
            }
        }],
        fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
    },
    angularCli: {
        environment: 'dev'
    },
    reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml', 'dots'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: false
});
};
```

My build.gradle file has properties for sonar:

```
sonarqube {
properties {
    // Sonar Specific properties
    property 'sonar.host.url', '' // This is the Sonar Server
    property "sonar.projectName", ""
    property "sonar.projectKey", ""
    property "sonar.sources", "./src"
    property "sonar.exclusions", "**/*.spec.js,**/test.ts,"
    property "sonar.language", "ts"
    property "sonar.typescript.lcov.reportPaths", "coverage/lcov/lcov.info"
    property "sonar.test.inclusions", "**/*.spec.ts"
}
}
```

Now, the problem is, the coverage on sonar doesn't reflect the coverage that I have tests for. Also, running locally I am not able to see the coverage/lcov/lcov.info file in my machine.

I am not sure what's going wrong in my code.

Answer (score -1):

Did you use this command to run the unit tests

```
ng test --code-coverage
```

This should produce the lcov.info file.